# Why did Babbage’s difference engine need to do polynomial coefficients to 30 decimal places?

Tags: trigonometry, logarithms, taylor-expansion

At the London Science Museum we see a wonderful model example of Babbage’s [Difference Engine](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_engine).

[image]

[image]

It says that it generated polynomial coefficients to 30 decimal places for use in trigonometry and logarithm tables.

To me 5-10 decimal places seems to be enough for most problems. This seems like an unnecessary level of accuracy for the navigation and construction at the time.

My question is: **Why did Babbage’s difference engine need to do polynomial coefficients to 30 decimal places?**

Comment: Double precision numbers have about 16 decimal digits, which is enough for most purposes in scientific computing. Just speculating, but I'd guess that Babbage just didn't realize that we don't need so many digits. I'd guess he also didn't have the idea of floating point numbers.

Comment: I read ( many years ago) a Scientific American article about a project at the University of Boston in the latter 20th century. They built a Babbage No, 2 according to Babbage's specs, using only materials and methods that he could have. It worked. The article reproduced  part of the first recursive computer  program for his  No. 2 (for calculating some Bessel functions), which was written by a woman (whose name I forget) and which also had the first "bug".

Comment: The program I am referring to was not part of the university project. It was part of Babbage's original project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We only need  [$39$  digits of $\pi$ to measure the circumference of a circle to the width of an  hydrogen atom](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/edu/news/2016/3/16/how-many-decimals-of-pi-do-we-really-need/) , yet we've calculated $\pi $ to a whopping [2 Quadrillion digits](http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-11313194). Why ?Because we can and it is a good test to run to find the efficiency of any computing device.

I'm guessing this is the same case and the longer digits were calculated just because they could and also would have the by-product of improving the accuracy of calculations. But in reality the number of digits depends on  the accuracy required and the problem in hand but  to me $10 $ digits seems like overkill.

Answer (score 0):

When these polynomials would be used in successive calculations, and/or part of larger problems such as various numerical methods, errors accumulate a lot faster than you think. A final answer with N decimal places correct needs a lot more precision than a polynomial with N decimal places.

Also note that for very large $x^n$ (or possibly very small) in a polynomial $p(x)$, say $x^n \approx 10^{10}$, an error in the 5th decimal place would be very significant in relation to $x$.